# Wordpress - Custom taxonomies not working with permalinks - 404

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, taxonomy

I'm new to wordpress and I've been through the Codex on CPT and custom taxonomies thoroughly along with several tutorias.  Apparently I am missing something, but I have not been able to figure it out as I keep getting 404 on taxonomies only. And yes, I have been going to permalinks, and clicking 'save changes' to reset the cache.

Here is my current setup:

I have a CPT as 'people' and a taxonomy 'activities'.  The activities are predefined in a metabox, so I have swimmer, runner, cyclist.

Data is saving and I have created 3 people each in the different taxonomy for testing, so a call to any grouping should produce 1 post.

What I am trying to accomplish is have my url display the taxonomy name, thus filtering the result:

mydomain.com/people/swimmer
mydomain.com/people/runner
etc...

I am able to get a list of CPT's
mydomain.com/people

and I can get the single posts:
mydomain.com/people/person-title-field

I would like to solve this problem with code rather than a plugin - I prefer the 'learning by doing' approach, as this pays off in the long run.

Here is my code from my functions.php file.  If someone could be so kind as to tell me what I'm missing or have configured incorrectly would be much appreciated.

```
function create_people_post_type()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => __( 'People' ),
        'singular_name'         => __( 'Person' ),
        'search_items'          => __("Search People"),
        'all_items'             => __("All People"),
        'parent_item'           => __("Parent Person"),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __("Parent Person"),
        'edit_item'             => __("Edit Person"),
        'update_item'           => __("Update Person"),
        'add_new_item'          => __("Add New Person"),
        'new_item_name'         => __("New Person's Name")
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', ),
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'menu_position'         => 6,
        'has_archive'           => true
    );

    register_post_type( 'people', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'create_people_post_type');

function create_activities_taxonomy()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => __( 'activities' ),
        'singular_name'         => __( 'activity' ),
        'search_items'          => __("Search activities"),
        'all_items'             => __("All activities"),
        'parent_item'           => __("Parent activity"),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __("Parent activity"),
        'edit_item'             => __("Edit activity"),
        'update_item'           => __("Update activity"),
        'add_new_item'          => __("Add New activity"),
        'new_item_name'         => __("New activity's Name")
    );

    $args = array(
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => false,
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'query_var'             => false,
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'has_archive'           => true
    );

    register_taxonomy('activities','people', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'create_activities_taxonomy');

function activities_metabox()
{
    add_meta_box(
        'activities_box_id',
        'Activities',
        'activities_custom_box_html',
        'people',
        'side',
        'low'
    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'activities_metabox');

function activities_custom_box_html($post)
{
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'activities_custom_box_html_nonce');
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_activities_meta_key', true);
    ?>
    <label for="activities_field">Select Department</label>
    <select name="activities_field" id="activities_field" class="postbox">
        <option value="runner" <?php selected($value, 'runner'); ?>>Runner</option>
        <option value="swimmer" <?php selected($value, 'swimmer'); ?>>Swimmer</option>
        <option value="cyclist" <?php selected($value, 'cyclist'); ?>>Cyclist</option>

    </select>
    <?php
}

function activities_save_postdata($post_id)
{
    if (array_key_exists('activities_field', $_POST)) {
        update_post_meta(
            $post_id,
            '_activities_meta_key',
            $_POST['activities_field']
        );
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'activities_save_postdata');
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you created the page taxonomy-activities.php ?

Comment: Yes, I used the archive page as a template.  But I still get a 404.  Permalinks are set to the Post Name option

Comment: can you create a page taxonomy.php or taxonomy-activities.php and  check that it redirects to that page or not? and don't forget to click on save permalinks

Comment: Yes, I have created both and saved permalinks.  Still getting a 404. I tried several combinations on the URL just to make sure:  mydomain.com/people/runner,  mydomain.com/people/activities/runner,  mydomain.com/activities/runner.  From what I understand in the Codex, mydomain.com/people/runner should work.

Comment: people is your custom post type and activities is your taxonomy then mydomain.com/activities/runner should work.. when you access taxonomy archive then post type is not included in url

Comment: Yes, I tried mydomain.com/activities/runner.  Couldn't get any of them to work.  Any other suggestions?  Maybe I missed something in my source code?

Comment: why are you storing it in a metabox? taxonomies will be automatically show on right side like categories shows in a default blog posts. remove the custom meta box and activities_save_postdata function from your code. define runner, swimmer, and cyclist in a box defined by wp on right hand side and then try access  "mydomain.com/activities/runner"